# Search a record by Date converting it to UTC, C# SQL Server Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, entity-framework-5

I have the following table

TableOne

```
Id  Date                Activity
1  10/11/2013 9:00am   Interview
2  11/11/2013 10:00am  Group Discussion
```

and so on, its stored in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format

The Dates are stored in UTC format and I store the TimeZone information of the user.
So I convert the DateTime given by the User into UTC using the TimeZone information.

Now when displaying all the records in a list on a page to the user(I convert the UTC time back to the user's local time), I'm allowing the user to search the list by date.

That's where the problem occurs.

**If I'm in IST now which is (UTC + 5.30am), and I enter the Date in the search box as 10/11/2013, and I convert it into UTC I get 9/11/2013 6.30pm because when I convert 10/11/2013 to DateTime I get 10/11/2013 12:00AM and then I convert it to UTC, and my search fails there because 9/11/2013 is not equal to 10/11/2013.**

Any solution for this which can handle this issue???

Comment: Are you storing it as a string? In MS SQL RDMBS Datetimes types are stored as float numbers, they are just showed as localized dates and times.

Comment: no I'm storing them as DateTime, just wrote them roughly in the question

Comment: That should be the expected behavior. The dates stored in the database in UTC format need to occur on `9/11/2013` so when translated back they match the results for `10/11/2013`. Perhaps the issue is somewhere else?

Comment: the issue is because of the time, when a record is add to the table the date and time are provided and then converted and stored into database in UTC. Where as in search the Date gets appended with 12:00Am and then gets converted to UTC causing the date to change the previous date.

Answer (score 0):

First you are not storing in a localized (pt-BR?) format, but your input is (there's a huge difference).

Second you cast a date to a datetime in that search box and get 12 hours added to that date, why? Even if your cast don't adds 12 hours (you can get 10/11/2013 00:00) depending on our time zone that ill be cast to 09/11/2013.

Answer (score 0):

give you a demo,I think you see this you will know.

**StartTime** and **EndTime** now has a **middletime** for UTC

```
ticketAcct.CheckOffRuleControlTimes = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ticketGroup.ControlTimeRule.ControlTimeItems);
```

change the **middletime**  to **localtime**

```
List<ControlTimeItem> controlTimeItemList = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<ControlTimeItem>>(TicketAcct.CheckOffRuleControlTimes);
        controlTimeItemList.ForEach(p => { p.StartTime = p.StartTime.ToLocalTime(); p.EndTIme = p.EndTIme.ToLocalTime(); });
```

so the same as you 
when you save you save a **middletime** 
and search to use **middletime** value 
but if you want to show ,you can change the **middletime** to **localtime**